# ListView text not showing with view switcher

Tags: android, listview

So I have a fragment where once the progress bar is done loading, a listview of items should appear, however while the LogCat shows me that these items are indeed by collected, there is nothing coming on there screen. Why is this? Here is my code and xml:

Java:

```
private class showView extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Boolean>{
    Ride[] rides;
    ArrayList<String>aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Ride> ri = new ArrayList<Ride>();
    String[] rideInfo;
    String sessionToken;
    String deviceId;
    String startZip;
    long start;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        deviceId = device.getDeviceId();
        sessionToken = SessionManager.getSessionToken(getActivity());
        if(sessionToken == null){
            MainActivity.startSignIn(ctx);
        }

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... stuff){





        Log.d("addressList", addressList.toString());

        startZip = addressList.get(0).getPostalCode();

        start = (long)c.get(Calendar.DATE);

        reRi = RestQuery.rideSearch(sessionToken, deviceId, startZip, 20, null, 0, start, start);
        if(!(reRi == null)){
        ri = reRi.getRides();
        if(!(ri == null)){
        rides = ri.toArray(new Ride[ri.size()]);
        if(!(rides == null)){

        for(int x = 0; x < rides.length; x++){
            String name = rides[x].getName();
            String type = rides[x].getType();
            String date = rides[x].getStartDate();
            String startL = rides[x].getStartLocation();
            String endL = rides[x].getEndLocation();

            String rideI = type + "/n" + name + "/n" + date + "/n" + startL + "-" + endL;
            Log.d("ride info",rideI);
            System.out.println(rideI);

            aList.add(rideI);
        }

        rideInfo = aList.toArray(new String[aList.size()]);
        }
        else{
            MainActivity.startSignIn(ctx);
        }
        }
        else{
            MainActivity.startSignIn(ctx);
        }
        }

        else{
            MainActivity.startSignIn(ctx);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Boolean results){
        results = false;
        if(reRi.getResult().getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Ok") || reRi.getResult().getMessage().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("I00001")){
            results = true;
        }
        if(results){
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(ctx,rideInfo);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        switcher.showNext();
        }

        else if(!results){
            if(reRi.getResult().getMessage().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("E00012") || reRi.getResult().getMessage().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("E00011")){
                MainActivity.startSignIn(ctx);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Couldn't access rides", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        }
    }





private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;


      public Adapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.browse_fragment, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;



      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_fragment, parent, false);
            TextView txtView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.yo);

            txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(values[position]));

            return rowView;
    }


}
```

}xml:

```
<ViewSwitcher 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/browse_fragment_switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Finding possible rides"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCollection"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation = "vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/show_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No rides could be found at this time"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call:

```
adapter.notiftyDataSetChanged();
```

after you update the aList contents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Try that, let me know if it helps.

If you want to post the rest of your code (the enclosing if, where you start the async task) I can provide more comments.

Comment: Hi, that method does not work. I posted the rest of the code.

Comment: What do you get when you use that method?  I suspect its an exception about accessing the UI from the wrong thread.